# inserting text between two lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following python file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, argparse
from pbsuite.utils.setupLogging import *
....
```

and I would like to change it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')
import sys, argparse
from pbsuite.utils.setupLogging import *
```

Unfotunately, `sed -i.bak '2 s|^.*$|sys.path.append(${OUTPUT})|g' a.py` overwrites `import sys, argparse` and does not replace `$OUTPUT` variable with its content

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sys.path.append(${OUTPUT})
from pbsuite.utils.setupLogging import *
```

How is it possible to fix it for Mac and Linux?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed "2i\sys.path.append(\'/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24\')" file.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')
import sys, argparse
from pbsuite.utils.setupLogging import *
....
```

**awk solution**

```
$ a="sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')"

$ echo $a
sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')

$ awk -v ins="${a}" 'NR==2{printf("%s\n",ins)}1' a.txt
#!/usr/bin/env python
sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')
import sys, argparse
from pbsuite.utils.setupLogging import *
....
```

Comment: Under Mac I got this error `sed: 1: "2i\sys.path.append(\'/a ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21950403

Comment: yes, the mac solution work for mac, but it does not work under linux. Is there any platform independent solution?

Comment: check.. whether awk works for you in linux and mac... i am sure.. the sed will work on linux and mac..

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i.bak -e "1G;s|\n|&sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')|" yourpyfile

ed -s yourpyfile <<\cmd
1a
sys.path.append('/anaconda/conda-bld/pbsuite_1490823990330/_t_env/opt/pbsuite-15.8.24')
.
wq
cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a shell quoting issue; the single quotes you use make the `${OUTPUT}` literal:

```
$ export OUTPUT="a test"
$ echo 'bla blah ${OUTPUT} blah'
bla blah ${OUTPUT} blah
$ echo 'blah blah '"${OUTPUT}"' blah'                   
blah blah a test blah
$
```

Note that `'blah blah '${OUTPUT}' blah'` may appear correct though has subtle differences from the above version with the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

as per your condition, if you want to add one line between those two lines then first you need to change **single quote to double quote** , then only `sed` will understand that you have shell variable and use something like this,

Note that space between **1** and **a\sys.path.append(${OUTPUT})** is important.

```
sed -i.bak "1 a\sys.path.append(${OUTPUT})" a.py
```